# How is the trading engine from Binance developed and designed?

Tags: exchanges, exchange-order, exchange-software

As a early adopter of BNB and fan of Binance's recent world domination, one thing that always got me curious was about how Binance deals with these massive inflows of requests in theirs trading engine/website.

Is the system of trading and cryptocurrency wallets fully developed and designed in-house or they have the assistance of some third-party provider? If they have some third-party technology, do you know which one?

I ask this because of the recent surge of a lot of companies providing white label services for digital asset exchanges.

Thanks in advance!

Obs: Binance is just an example, other exchanges with high volume and multiple coins listed also responds the doubt!